# Facebook iPhone app submit Issues

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

In my iPhoe app user want to login and it was successfully achieved by integrating the latest facebook SDK.But when i want to comment the page post to FB i need the **`publish_action`** permission.I submitted my iphone app to FB developer console by adding all required things.I got the following message from facebook.

We could not reproduce the requested permission. Please submit detailed, step-by-step instructions in the "Add Notes" section of the permission, and make sure to provide the relevant version of your app. See here for additional information on login permission requirements.

Comment: Kindly give me the solutions ASAP

Comment: Facebook has changed the scenario, in order to get publish_action permission from users you have to provide them the steps with screenshots and tell them how your app works. They will review and approve if they consider the app. After their approval only you can publish on behalf of the user through your application.

Comment: @JanakNirmal please read my question.I already submit my add to Facebook App center.But i got the issue message after reviewing my app.

Comment: @JanakNirmal can you give me the example tutorial for submitting app to Facebook app center

Comment: You have to explain how it works in your app. No one here will be able to do that

Comment: Just provide them the location where you need publish_action permission with the screenshot as they are not able to locate where you are actually going to use that permission.